# Print Flickr variables from API using json_decode

Tags: php, api, flickr, json

I want to create a flickr photo url by calling variables from my json_decoded api request, but I can't get it to output any values...

Here's the code:

```
    $flickr = file_get_contents("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=b5c6ad8347e6dbeb62743d1be36dc9e1&photoset_id=72157628996146229&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", TRUE);
    $flickr = json_decode($flickr, TRUE);
    var_dump($flickr);

echo $flickr[photoset][photo][id];
```

Sadly this is outputting nothing...

Any ideas?

Simple ones :)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Accessing array elements

```
echo $flickr[photoset][photo][id];
```

Should be:

```
echo $flickr['photoset']['photo']['id'];
```

In PHP [strings <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) must be surrounded by either single (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) when used as array element keys. If they are not then PHP will attempt to evaluate them as [constants <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/constant).

### Looping over the dataset

In this case [`json_decode()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/json_decode) is returning an array of data so you will need to loop over it to access it:

```
foreach ($flickr['photoset']['photo'] as $item) {
    echo $item['id'];
}
```

For more information on PHPs [`foreach` see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 1):

`$flickr['photoset']['photo']` is an array of photos. To print all photo ids you should:

```
foreach ($flickr['photoset']['photo'] as $photo) {
    echo $photo['id'];
}
```

Also, make sure you quote array keys (`['photoset']` instead of `[photoset]`)